# jquery tabs not working with multiple fullcalendar

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I assume I am missing something trivial, but I cannot get jQuery tabs to work with multiple fullCalendar implementations.  ALL calendars are rendered instantly and show one above the next.

Here is the most simplified JSFiddle I could come up with to show the issue:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlrhett/L4kqC/23/)

I saw a similar question posted, but the solution to add $("..").fullCalendar("render") to the .tabs({show: ...}) seems based on an earlier version of fullCalendar and in any case did not work.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:   http://jsfiddle.net/L4kqC/30/

Move the calendar elements inside the element on which you are calling tabs() (as per the jQuery UI doc: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ )

And call tabs() after fullcalendar()  (probably because fullcalendar doesn't like to be instantiated on hidden elements).